# Cannot use for tag to iterate through Array List in Pebble Template Engine

Tags: java, template-engine, pebble

I have been trying to iterate through an Array List of items with `{% for item in items %}` syntax to no avail.
Keeps throwing

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)
    at com.mitchellbosecke.pebble.template.Scope.put(Scope.java:53)
    at   com.mitchellbosecke.pebble.template.ScopeChain.put(ScopeChain.java:61)
at com.mitchellbosecke.pebble.template.EvaluationContext.put(EvaluationContext.java:162) exception.
```

Tried with primitive arrays, maps, many types of List implementations, always this is the result. When doing an iterable test, the array list returns true, so I think it should be iterable using the for tag. Am I doing something wrong? Please find the code below.

```
PebbleTemplate template = pebbleEngine.getTemplate(
  "{% if menuItems is iterable %}{% for menuItem in menuItems %}" +
  " \"{{ menuItem }}\" this" +
  "{% endfor %}{% else %}nope{% endif %}");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

List<String> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
menuItems.add("menu item1");
menuItems.add("menu item2");
menuItems.add("menu item 3");

template.evaluate(writer, Collections.<String,Object>singletonMap("menuItems", menuItems));
System.out.println(writer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the use of the singleton map. 
Use an `HashMap` instead and should work.

Explanation. The `Scope` is initialised as follows:

```
public Scope(Map<String, Object> backingMap, boolean isLocal) {
    this.backingMap = (Map)(backingMap == null?new HashMap():backingMap);
    this.isLocal = isLocal;
}
```

so it actually reuses the map you are providing. When it calls `put` over the `Map`, it throws an exception because it is a singleton.

Comment: That's weird. Never expected the map I am providing for evaluation of the template to be updated by the for loop mechanism. Anyways works like a charm. This is what I have in the map after the for loop. {loop={length=3, index=2}, menuItems=[menu item1, menu item2, menu item 3], menuItem=menu item 3}

Comment: @javabot I agree! I do not like this approach at all. It is not defensive enough! 
To justify it, I use Spring and also there the model is a Map, that probably cannot be considered immutable.  In fact, with a single controller call it can be passed to a method annotated with `@RequestMapping` but also to several methods annotated with `@ModelAttribute`. If it is provided as immutable, then it cannot be populated dynamically.